# Rolling join grouped by a second variable in data.table

Tags: r, join, data.table

Hello I would like to perform a rolling join in R using the `data.table` package. There are multiple matches when joining on the "Date" column so I would like to use the `by` argument in `data.table` on the "Field" column to keep data from different fields from being joined together.

**Example Data**

```
d1<-structure(list(Field = c("6", "W62", "6", "6", "12S", "19-1", 
"6", "6", "12S", "7", "6", "12S", "W62", "6", "12S", "W62", "12S", 
"6", "6", "7", "12S", "12S", "W62", "7", "12S", "6", "12S", "7", 
"12S", "7", "6", "7", "12S", "7", "6", "6", "6", "6", "12S", 
"7", "7", "6", "6", "12S", "7", "12S", "12S", "12S", "19-1", 
"6"), Date = structure(c(16994, 17240, 17240, 17401, 17048, 17417, 
17387, 17394, 17382, 17414, 17029, 17403, 17045, 17359, 17179, 
17281, 17152, 16972, 16987, 17042, 17282, 17415, 17281, 17266, 
17179, 17190, 17057, 17380, 17280, 17178, 17178, 17343, 17373, 
17043, 17190, 17343, 17253, 16981, 17079, 17043, 17270, 17366, 
16981, 17357, 17366, 17415, 17079, 17190, 17385, 17008), class = "Date"), 
    NlbsAcre = c(NA, 18874.6557383659, 2477.08251404958, NA, 
    NA, 19658.0054165823, NA, NA, 12621.0827111083, NA, NA, 16764.41968227, 
    16764.9745173044, NA, 7671.24950330348, 21341.6444661863, 
    5197.26333885612, NA, NA, NA, 39560.8958554292, 18162.4040880297, 
    22578.1487456647, 15842.9161753361, 3613.95523726973, 2601.07083566694, 
    17766.9873538952, NA, 44728.1837479613, 2279.60909695434, 
    2014.7720270382, NA, 14847.7006686211, NA, 3082.31758038481, 
    NA, 2427.53558465175, NA, 23641.2999848709, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    5928.31591997149, NA, 22162.2028819815, 18972.2228621189, 
    6534.4257935542, 12630.9231775315, NA)), .Names = c("Field", 
"Date", "NlbsAcre"), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
-50L), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x0000000006540788>)

d2<-structure(list(Field = c("6", "W62", "7", "12S", "19-1", "12S", 
"6", "6", "19-1", "19-1", "6", "7", "W62", "19-1", "12S", "7", 
"19-1", "7", "12S", "12S", "12S", "7", "6", "7", "6", "7", "W62", 
"19-1", "6", "6", "12S", "12S", "6", "6", "12S", "6", "12S", 
"19-1", "6", "W62", "W62", "6", "7", "7", "6", "19-1", "W62", 
"6", "12S", "7"), Date = structure(c(16993, 17140, 17208, 17443, 
17063, 16948, 17415, 16926, 17316, 16922, 16981, 17043, 17219, 
17252, 17392, 17244, 17179, 17017, 17042, 17031, 17013, 17104, 
17273, 16954, 17364, 16993, 17168, 17028, 17208, 16966, 17241, 
16945, 17038, 17169, 17379, 17183, 17238, 17054, 17244, 16952, 
17044, 17359, 17219, 17303, 17007, 17151, 16926, 17178, 17382, 
17364), class = "Date"), TotN = c(79.244802845739, 94.193700050628, 
21.075505564932, 692.152760834712, 224.689064446728, 172.576578578436, 
47.406177406404, 102.53239575903, 818.80997295717, 476.174916307807, 
125.828033450364, 58.270026966444, 75.465909993456, 435.049246131543, 
337.913876678769, 31.714327953234, 305.353940577156, 72.621457768224, 
393.815453005314, 428.540114240892, 318.97091713563, 73.888113736431, 
79.0380747113805, 147.493527174027, 65.5311189906495, 59.269732271703, 
119.390398108236, 110.706003557451, 21.96790939404, 149.060445984684, 
128.143343232486, 208.621943093862, 75.770138571561, 47.496596179338, 
132.723654607278, 43.92222198012, 145.150910469252, 215.88105225024, 
21.393670871196, 72.969536052, 86.335878117078, 103.524169592979, 
19.920230115264, 44.968722966108, 62.244487239885, 338.593490463303, 
96.7285416279375, 45.537296152302, 422.630318314444, 58.5336350807685
)), .Names = c("Field", "Date", "TotN"), class = c("data.table", 
"data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -50L), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x0000000006540788>)
```

**What I have tried**

This is my attempt to perform a rolling join on the "Date" column, grouped `by` the "Field" column. Obviously I can split the data by "Field" and process separately but I would like to avoid that option.

```
d1[d2, roll = "nearest", on = .(Date), by = .(Field)]

Error in `[.data.table`(d1, d2, roll = "nearest", on = .(Date), by = .(Field)) : 
  'by' or 'keyby' is supplied but not j
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You were almost there.

You can join on multiple columns simultaneously. So, in addition to "Date", you can include "Field" in the `on` clause. But please note the description of the `roll` argument in `?data.table`:

> Rolling joins apply to the *last* join column

Thus, for "Date" to be used for the rolling join, specify it as the *last* variable in `on`:

```
library(data.table)
d1[d2, roll = "nearest", on = .(Field, Date)]
```

For better verification, the result can be ordered

```
d1[d2, roll = "nearest", on = .(Field, Date)][order(Field, Date)]
```

> ```
>     Field       Date  NlbsAcre      TotN
>  1:   12S 2016-05-24        NA 208.62194
>  2:   12S 2016-05-27        NA 172.57658
>  3:   12S 2016-07-31        NA 318.97092
>  4:   12S 2016-08-18        NA 428.54011
>  5:   12S 2016-08-29        NA 393.81545
>  6:   12S 2017-03-13 44728.184 145.15091
>  7:   12S 2017-03-16 44728.184 128.14334
>  8:   12S 2017-08-01 12621.083 132.72365
>  9:   12S 2017-08-04 12621.083 422.63032
> 10:   12S 2017-08-14 12621.083 337.91388
> 11:   12S 2017-10-04 22162.203 692.15276
> 12:  19-1 2016-05-01 12630.923 476.17492
> 13:  19-1 2016-08-15 12630.923 110.70600
> 14:  19-1 2016-09-10 12630.923 215.88105
> 15:  19-1 2016-09-19 12630.923 224.68906
> 16:  19-1 2016-12-16 12630.923 338.59349
> 17:  19-1 2017-01-13 12630.923 305.35394
> 18:  19-1 2017-03-27 12630.923 435.04925
> 19:  19-1 2017-05-30 12630.923 818.80997
> 20:     6 2016-05-05        NA 102.53240
> 21:     6 2016-06-14        NA 149.06045
> 22:     6 2016-06-29        NA 125.82803
> 23:     6 2016-06-29        NA 125.82803
> 24:     6 2016-07-11        NA  79.24480
> 25:     6 2016-07-25        NA  62.24449
> 26:     6 2016-08-25        NA  75.77014
> 27:     6 2017-01-03  2014.772  47.49660
> 28:     6 2017-01-12  2014.772  45.53730
> 29:     6 2017-01-17  2014.772  43.92222
> 30:     6 2017-02-11  3082.318  21.96791
> 31:     6 2017-03-19  2477.083  21.39367
> 32:     6 2017-04-17  2427.536  79.03807
> 33:     6 2017-07-12        NA 103.52417
> 34:     6 2017-07-17        NA  65.53112
> 35:     6 2017-09-06        NA  47.40618
> 36:     7 2016-06-02        NA 147.49353
> 37:     7 2016-07-11        NA  59.26973
> 38:     7 2016-08-04        NA  72.62146
> 39:     7 2016-08-30        NA  58.27003
> 40:     7 2016-08-30        NA  58.27003
> 41:     7 2016-10-30        NA  73.88811
> 42:     7 2017-02-11  2279.609  21.07551
> 43:     7 2017-02-22  2279.609  19.92023
> 44:     7 2017-03-19 15842.916  31.71433
> 45:     7 2017-05-17        NA  44.96872
> 46:     7 2017-07-17        NA  58.53364
> 47:   W62 2016-05-05 16764.975  96.72854
> 48:   W62 2016-05-31 16764.975  72.96954
> 49:   W62 2016-08-31 16764.975  86.33588
> 50:   W62 2016-12-05 16764.975  94.19370
> 51:   W62 2017-01-02 18874.656 119.39040
> 52:   W62 2017-02-22 18874.656  75.46591
>     Field       Date  NlbsAcre      TotN
> ```

Comment: Thanks! For me the key here is that the column that you are trying to roll by must be the last column listed in the on argument. I actually tried this method but was unsuccessful because I supplied Field after Date. This produces the error `Error in bmerge(i, x, leftcols, rightcols, io, xo, roll, rollends, nomatch,  : 
  roll='nearest' can't be applied to a character column, yet.`.