# both rolling join and exact join with data.table

Tags: r, join, merge, data.table

I want to do a rolling join on one variable, but considering an exact match on another variable.

I can do a rolling join this way :

```r
library(data.table)

dt1 <- data.table(id1 = 1:4, foo = c("a","b","a","b"), val1 = c(10,20,30,34))
dt2 <- data.table(id2 = 1:4, foo = c("a","b","a","b"), val2 = c(15,25,35,45))

dt1
#>    id1 foo val1
#> 1:   1   a   10
#> 2:   2   b   20
#> 3:   3   a   30
#> 4:   4   b   34

dt2
#>    id2 foo val2
#> 1:   1   a   15
#> 2:   2   b   25
#> 3:   3   a   35
#> 4:   4   b   45

dt2[,val1:=val2]
dt2[dt1, on = .(val1), roll = -Inf]
#>    id2 foo val2 val1 id1 i.foo
#> 1:   1   a   15   10   1     a
#> 2:   2   b   25   20   2     b
#> 3:   3   a   35   30   3     a
#> 4:   3   a   35   34   4     b
```

But what if I want to match `foo` as well ?
My desired output is the following:

```
#>    id2 foo val2 val1 id1 
#> 1:   1   a   15   10   1     
#> 2:   2   b   25   20   2     
#> 3:   3   a   35   30   3     
#> 4:   4   b   45   34   4
```

This won't work :

```
dt2[dt1, on = .(val1, foo), roll = -Inf]
#>    id2 foo val2 val1 id1
#> 1:  NA   a   NA   10   1
#> 2:  NA   b   NA   20   2
#> 3:  NA   a   NA   30   3
#> 4:  NA   b   NA   34   4
```

Comment: `dt2[dt1, on = .(foo, val1), roll = -Inf]` works for me?

Comment: Is it a bug, a join-calculus thing, or a "feature" that the order of `on=` affects it in this way?

Comment: @r2evans I think the column to roll by has to be last in `on`, I'm not sure why though

Comment: Regarding the order, at least it is explicit in `?data.table`: "Rolling joins apply to the last join column"

Comment: indeed Henrik, it was all in the doc, in the roll argument : `When i is a data.table and its row matches to all but the last x join column, and its value in the last i join column falls in a gap...`, and later `Rolling joins apply to the last join column` as you wrote. Please any of you can answer this, if not I'll self answer.

Comment: Related: [Rolling join by in data.table R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47897193/rolling-join-by-in-data-table-r). Q: "perform a rolling join on the Date column by the Field column"; A: "include Field in the `on` clause (with Date being _last_ as it will be used for the rolling join)"

Comment: Thanks, I think with our comments here this is better marked as a dupe :)